# How can I assign a coordinate to a javascript variable, and draw lines using moveTo and lineTo around these variables?

Tags: javascript, html

I couldn't figure out how to assign a coordinate to a variable so I created two individual ones for length and height and replaced (0,0) with the height/width variables respectively. I then used moveTo and lineTo to attempt to draw a square around the variable coordinate points by adding +50 or -50 (px)to the variable coordinate but nothing is being drawn. How can I make a square drawn around in this case on the coordinate point 1 (P1W,P1H)?

```js
   var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var WIDTH = canvas.width;
    var HEIGHT = canvas.height;

    var P1H = HEIGHT/4*1
    var P1W = WIDTH/4*1

    var P2H = HEIGHT/4*2
    var P2W = WIDTH/4*2

    var P3H = HEIGHT/4*3
    var P3W = WIDTH/4*3

    var P4H = HEIGHT/4*4
    var P4W = WIDTH/4*4

    var SqP1 = ctx.moveTo(P1W-50,P1H+50);
    var SqP2 = ctx.moveTo(P1W+50,P1H+50);
    var SqP3 = ctx.moveTo(P1W-50,P1H-50);
    var SqP4 = ctx.moveTo(P1W+50,P1H-50);

    function draw() {
    SqP1;
    ctx.lineTo(P1W+50,P1H+50);
    SqP2;
    ctx.lineTo(P1W-50,P1H-50);
    SqP3;
    ctx.lineTo(P1W+50,P1H-50);
    SqP4;
    ctx.lineTo(P1W-50,P1H+50);
    }

    if (1===1) {
    draw();
    }
    console.log(WIDTH);
    console.log(HEIGHT);
```

```css
    html {
    background-color:#0d3677;
    }

    html,head {
    width:  100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    }
```

```html
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you move and draw lines, last statement needs to be ctx.stroke();  I have drawn the square from top left - top right - bottom right - bottom left - top left.  I have also marked the center of the square.  Hope this helps.

```
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
        <script>
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var WIDTH = canvas.width;
    var HEIGHT = canvas.height;

    var P1H = HEIGHT/4*1;
    var P1W = WIDTH/4*1;

    console.log(P1H +"  , " + P1W);

//    var P2H = HEIGHT/4*2;
//    var P2W = WIDTH/4*2;
//
//    var P3H = HEIGHT/4*3;
//    var P3W = WIDTH/4*3;
//
//    var P4H = HEIGHT/4*4;
//    var P4W = WIDTH/4*4;
//
//    var SqP1 = ctx.moveTo(P1W-50,P1H+50);
//    var SqP2 = ctx.moveTo(P1W+50,P1H+50);
//    var SqP3 = ctx.moveTo(P1W-50,P1H-50);
//    var SqP4 = ctx.moveTo(P1W+50,P1H-50);


    function draw() {
      ctx.fillRect(P1W,P1H,1,1); // fill in the pixel at (P1W,P1H)
      ctx.moveTo(P1W-50,P1H-50);
      ctx.lineTo(P1W+50,P1H-50);
      ctx.lineTo(P1W+50,P1H+50);
      ctx.lineTo(P1W-50,P1H+50);
      ctx.lineTo(P1W-50,P1H-50);
      ctx.stroke();
    }

    if (1===1) {
    draw();
    }
    console.log(WIDTH);
    console.log(HEIGHT);

        </script>
```